# After executing the bake(), it doesn't show all the predictors and the outcome in the result

Tags: r, data-modeling

I am writing a model for my dataset. Once the bake() is executed, the result has one missing predictor and the outcome.

This happens after writing the **recipe steps**. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

```
top10_renewableEnergyProd_split <- initial_split(top10_renewableEnergyProd)
top10_renewableEnergyProd_train <- training(top10_renewableEnergyProd_split)
top10_renewableEnergyProd_test  <- testing(top10_renewableEnergyProd_split)

top10_renewableEnergyProd_recipe <- recipe(energyProd_2018 ~ country_name + energyProd_2016 + energyProd_2017 , data =  top10_renewableEnergyProd_train)

    #recipe steps
top10_renewableEnergyProd_recipe <- top10_renewableEnergyProd_recipe %>%
    step_center(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
    step_scale(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>% 
    step_corr(all_numeric())

top10_renewableEnergyProd_prep <- prep(top10_renewableEnergyProd_recipe, training = top10_renewableEnergyProd_train)

top10_renewableEnergyProd_bake <- bake(top10_renewableEnergyProd_prep, top10_renewableEnergyProd_train)

top10_renewableEnergyProd_bake

> dput(top10_renewableEnergyProd)
structure(list(type2 = c("Renewable", "Renewable", "Renewable", 
"Renewable", "Renewable", "Renewable", "Renewable", "Renewable", 
"Renewable", "Renewable"), country = c("DE", "ES", "FR", "IT", 
"NO", "PL", "SE", "TR", "UA", "UK"), country_name = c("Germany", 
"Spain", "France", "Italy", "Norway", "Poland", "Sweden", "Turkey", 
"Ukraine", "United Kingdom"), energyProd_2016 = c(147622, 103353, 
99885.054, 90756.826, 146557, 15468, 77505, 87090, 12097, 58909.047
), energyProd_2017 = c(175063, 84664, 93907.184, 86786.294, 146285, 
18187.708, 82540, 83536.342, 12082.6, 73113.964), energyProd_2018 = c(185226.211, 
99725.566, 113658.177, 96820, 146878.825, 15541.473, 77615.947, 
93425.906, 13843.9, 79955.967)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    country = c("DE", "ES", "FR", "IT", "NO", "PL", "SE", "TR", 
    "UA", "UK"), country_name = c("Germany", "Spain", "France", 
    "Italy", "Norway", "Poland", "Sweden", "Turkey", "Ukraine", 
    "United Kingdom"), type2 = c("Renewable", "Renewable", "Renewable", 
    "Renewable", "Renewable", "Renewable", "Renewable", "Renewable", 
    "Renewable", "Renewable"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
        3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(top10_renewableEnergyProd_bake)
structure(list(country_name = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("France", "Germany", "Italy", "Norway", 
"Spain", "Sweden", "Turkey", "United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), 
    energyProd_2016 = c(1.47285970883518, 0.0604065991667829, 
    -0.0502421869332435, -0.341488748282317, 1.4388796649716, 
    -0.764303423167326, -0.458483028395103, -1.35762858619557
    )), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```